# Invoke C++ function from C# module raises random crashes

Tags: c#, c++, interop, marshalling

My C# module has to communicate to a C++ dll that exposes a set of functions and need to process according to the data returned by the called function.

Here is my C# code where C++ function(Npr) is called,

```
 [DllImport("CppModule.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "Npr"), System.Security.SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
    public static extern IntPtr Npr([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]string moduleIDCur,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]string mName,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]string threadID,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]string sessionID,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]string reqID,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]string siteID,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]string siteName,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]string nodeOrder,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]string dateTime,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]string rType,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]string rCode,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]string headStr,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]string cookStr,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]string userAgent,
        int flag);

...
IntPtr rets =  Npr(reqHttp.Url.PathAndQuery,rAddr,Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.ToString(),sessionID,reqGUID,
                           siteID,siteName,nodeStr,DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US")),reqHttp.RequestType,
                          HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode.ToString(), headers, cookieStr, uAgent,
                           flag);             // Native Call from C#
...
```

In CppModule.dll

```
EXTERN_C WCHAR* __cdecl Npr(WCHAR* testString,WCHAR* mname,WCHAR* threadID,WCHAR* sessionID,
                                         WCHAR* rID,WCHAR* siteID,WCHAR* siteName,WCHAR* nodeOrder,
                                         WCHAR* dateTime,WCHAR* rType,WCHAR* rCode,WCHAR* headStr,WCHAR* cookieStr,WCHAR* uAgent,int flag)
{ ... ...  return wcharPtr;}
```

This Npr function call gives exception randomly. The exception message is `Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.` At the line number of Npr function call in  C#. I changed this function **Npr to return a WCHAR* recently** from where the random crash is keep on occuring. Am i missing any interop related marshaling or similar ?

Comment: Your C++ function returns a pointer, but what is it pointing to? And what is the function doing? If the crash is in the C++ function, we need to see it to be able to help.

Comment: What exactly is your reasoning for marshaling a `WCHAR*` return value as `IntPtr`?

Comment: Just a guess... Stop returning wchar* and do something like:

Comment: @AdamJachocki I need to get string from the C++ , how can i achieve it then?

Comment: @MaxLanghof Will get back the string by using  Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(rets) in C# side.

Comment: Is the C++ function really plain C++, or C++/CLI? If it's C++/CLI then perhaps use .NET strings instead (i.e. `String^`)? Or for plain C++ use `std::wstring`? For *all* strings, even the arguments.

Comment: @Sel_va - I showed you example in my comment :) Just treat it like an output parameter, not return. There may be some problems when you return pointer. Especially memory leaks that may lead to memory corruption problems.

Comment: @AdamJachocki Please read you comment again, it doesn't contain any code.

Comment: Hmmm, I don't know why it dissapeared :/ It should be on C++ side: bool Npr(wchar_t * pResultString, int & strLen, other params...) <- you should here copy the string into pResultString and then on C# side: static extern bool Npr(StringBuilder resultString, ref int strLen, other parameters) <- and you should here create resultString big enought and then call Npr.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, in my programs, if a C++ function return a string, I prefer to pass a StringBuilder in the parameters, and then modify it.

Something like :

```
[DllImport("CppModule.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "Npr"), System.Security.SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
public static extern void Npr(StringBuilder returnValue, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]string moduleIDCur,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]string mName,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]string threadID,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]string sessionID,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]string reqID,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]string siteID,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]string siteName,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]string nodeOrder,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]string dateTime,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]string rType,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]string rCode,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]string headStr,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]string cookStr,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]string userAgent,
    int flag);
...
Npr(returnValue, reqHttp.Url.PathAndQuery,rAddr,Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.ToString(),sessionID,reqGUID,
                       siteID,siteName,nodeStr,DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US")),reqHttp.RequestType,
                      HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode.ToString(), headers, cookieStr, uAgent,
                       flag);
```

...

In the c++ code :

```
EXTERN_C void __cdecl Npr(WCHAR * wcharPtr, WCHAR* testString,WCHAR* mname,WCHAR* threadID,WCHAR* sessionID, WCHAR* rID,WCHAR* siteID,WCHAR* siteName,WCHAR* nodeOrder, WCHAR* dateTime,WCHAR* rType,WCHAR* rCode,WCHAR* headStr,WCHAR* cookieStr,WCHAR* uAgent,int flag)
{ ... ... }
```